# Bootstrap popover is shown only once. why?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I implemented popover in html using jQuery.

However, if the popover is displayed and then disappeared, the same popover is not displayed again.

I also tried `css("display", "none")` but it didn't work.

Been stuck on this issue for 3 days. Please give me a solution.

Below is the code I wrote.

And if the same button is pressed twice or more, the following error occurs.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-danger', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var checkBtn = $(this);

        selected_line = checkBtn.text().substring(11) * 1;

        selected_td = checkBtn.parent();
        console.log(checkBtn.text())
        
        $(selected_td.children('#popover'+selected_line)).popover({
                trigger     :   'click',
                placement   :   'right',
                html        :   true,
                content     :   function() {
                    var pop =  selected_td.children('#advice_line'+selected_line);
                    pop.show();
                    return pop
                },
                container   :   'body'
        });

        //attach link text
        $('.popover-textarea').val($this.text()).focus();

        //hide any visible comment-popover
        $(selected_td.children('#popover'+selected_line)).not(this).popover('hide');
        var $this = $(this);

        //close on cancel
        $(selected_td.find('#popover_cancel'+selected_line)).click(function() {
            //$this.popover('dispose')
            $('#popover'+selected_line).popover('dispose')
        });

        //update link text on submit
        $(selected_td.find('#popover_submit'+selected_line)).click(function() {
            $this.text($('.popover-textarea').val());
            $this.popover('dispose');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a id="popover1" data-html="true" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="comments"
                            class="btn btn-danger">advice_line1</a>

    <div class="popover" style="display: none;" id="advice_line1">
        <div class="popover-arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header">Advice</h3>
        <div class="popover-body"><div class="popover-content"><textarea class="popover-textarea">advice_line1</textarea></div></div>
        <div class="popover-footer">
            <button id="popover_submit1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>&nbsp;
            <button id="popover_cancel1" type="button" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've edited your question to put the sample code into an executable snippet. Can you check that I've kept everything important intact? You should be able to revert the change if I've mixed anything up.

Comment: Did a fiddle with your code. I don't get any failure in console output. style="display: none;" is working.